# Sync the scrollbar with an animation/gif

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can someone please tell me how to sync the scrollbar with an animation/gif?

I don't mean to start the gif when the animation when the scrollbar reaches a certain point, I want it to be in sync with the position of the page.

Take the faraday future website for example (https://www.ff.com/en/).

Thanks!

ps sorry if im phrasing my questions poorly, this is my first post

Comment: you'll need to watch scroll position and trigger the relevant animations when the page scroll position hits the markers you've set. you can do this with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *"animation/gif"* you meant  *"animation **or** gif"*, it really depends on the animation. Skip everything and fast-forward to the yellow paragraph.

---

If what you meant was *"animated gif"*, the normal answer to your question should be: **"You can't"**.

As in... `.gif`s are not controllable in the way they expose an API you could send commands to and tell them to change speed, direction, or go to a specific frame. It's a file the browser renders with some params. If you want to change or override those params you need to reload it with the new set of params.

But before submitting my answer, I thought I should double check and see if the generally accepted paradigm of `"animated gif"` hasn't updated/changed recently, so I did some research (which I believe you could and should have done yourself ― if you did it, you should have specified and linked the resources in your question).

Apparently, what you want is doable by using a `<canvas>` element and coding the interface for controlling the `.gif` yourself, in `JavaScript`. [These guys](http://gifctrl.com/?q=yunggif.tumblr.com&g=http://66.media.tumblr.com/541a5a7a6d77d2cdecd5437547cee06e/tumblr_ofuvgx0pyS1s3gys4o1_400.gif) seem to have achieved it. However, the code controlling it is minified and [looks like this](http://gifctrl.com/js/59323623.app.js).

It's clearly not something someone would code for you over a StackOverflow question, as defined in [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> ... good answers would be too long for this format.   Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.